# Whats the difference between an object going down a dip and going up a hump, both of the same size?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

So this is a question from a past physics Olympiad paper. If a mass goes into a shallow dip or over a hump, both of the same size, how does the time to travel compare?

My thought process was that since both paths have the same height, they lose and gain the same amount of gravitational potential energy during the dip/hump and so they have the same final velocity and hence also time.

The correct answer was A, shorter time via the dip. Can someone explain why this is?

[image]

Comment: The average speed for the path via X is more than the path via Y. The ball keeps on gaining kinetic energy unitl it reaches the lowest point on the curve. And when the ball goes back up, it does so with a greater amount of kinetic energy. You can compare the two cases for a constant x  axis coordinate. For a particular x cordinate the speed of the ball will be greater in the former case. This gives the ball greater average speed for the total path.

Answer (score 1):

At any distance along the track, the speed of the body in the dip is greater than (or, on the flat, equal to) the speed of the body going over the bump, as its potential energy is less and its total energy is the same. So the  speed is faster everywhere and the time is less.

Same question as: if you throw a ball into the air and catch it, does it take longer - including the effect of air resistance - on the way up or down?

Comment: Didn't even think about that. Does this mean assuming there was no friction, a body would travel faster in a surface with many dips compared to a flat one?

Comment: Nice answer, but I am not sure if the example with the ball is relevant. Without air resistance, it should take the same time. With air resistance, falling should take more time.

Comment: True, but how do you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to imagine the hill and dip as two straight lines. One going up and the other going down. The initial velocity is the same for both, and the velocity after the hill/dip is the same because of conservation of energy. Therefore, the velocity must be different when the ball rolls up the hill, or through the dip.

When the ball rolls through the dip, it loses potential energy and gains kinetic energy. Therefore, the velocity at the bottom is greater than the initial velocity. Let that velocity be $v_1$.

When the ball rolls over the hill, it gains potential energy and loses kinetic energy. Therefore the velocity at the top is less than the initial velocity. Let that velocity be $v_2$.  Now, $$v_1>v_0>v_2$$

Because the distance for both is the same, we can use the formula $vt=d$ to solve for time. $$\frac dv=t$$
$$ \frac {d}{v_1}=t_1 \space\space \frac{d}{v_2}=t_2$$$$t_1<t_2$$

The actual velocity is given by $$PE+KE=PE_0+KE_0 \Rightarrow PE-PE_0+KE-KE_0 = 0 \Rightarrow mgh-mgh_0+\frac 1 2 mv^2-\frac 12 mv_0^2$$